# MySQL query. How to pull a specific entry first, then show the rest?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pulling a whole table worth of data. What's inside doesn't really matter.

```
SELECT entry_id, title 
FROM tablename 
WHERE this = 'that' 
    AND something = 'foobar' 
ORDER BY title ASC
```

As you see i'm ordering by title in asc, which is exactly what i need. However, the VERY FIRST entry i want to display does not start with A or 0, in fact i'm unaware of what the entry title is, i figure that out dynamically.

So my question is how can i pull out that 1 entry first, than show the rest of the results without having to run 2 mysql queries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `case` to put 1 item first

```
SELECT entry_id, title 
FROM tablename 
WHERE this = 'that' AND something = 'foobar' 
ORDER BY case when title = 'some_title' 
              then 1
              else 2 
         end, title ASC
```

Comment: Just `title = 'some_title'` suffices as it returns either `1` or `0`.

Comment: Wait, i'm a little confused when title = 'some title' what do i say for else?

Comment: `some_title` is the title you want to pull first. That one gets the sort number 1. All other records (else) get sort number 2 - so they are after that entry. After that the records get normally sorted after the title.

Comment: @Gumbo: But shouldnt it then be `title <> ' some_title'`? `0` comes before `1`. Anyway that would only work for MySQL.